# method call not happening for method while unit testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have code like below trying to unit test it

```
@Service
class MainClass {
public void simpleExe() {
webclient.post()
.uri("url")
.header(----)
.bodyValue(ReqPojo)
.retrieve()
.bodyToMono(Response.class)
.flatMap(this::add); **this line is running but the call not happening to add method**
}

private Mono<Response> add() {
// doing some calculation
}
}
```

Test class

```
@SpringBootTest
class MainClassTest {

//mocked few other service calls

@Autowired
MainClass mainClass;
@Test
public void testsimpleExe() {
   mainClass.simpleExe();
 }
}
```

**this::add control coming to this line but call not happening to add method.**
what could be the issue. any thing missing?

Comment: I doubt it is called as there is no `@Test` on your test method.

Comment: @knittl you are right, I Just kept some sample code, I updated question now

Comment: @M.Deinum, in question i missed it

Comment: That is reactive code, nothing subscribes to it, so it does exactly that nothing.

Answer (score 0):

From the first code snippet the line `int a = this::add;` does not compile because incompatible types: int is not a [functional interface](https://java-8-tips.readthedocs.io/en/stable/funcinterfaces.html#functional-interfaces)

```
@Service
public class MainClass {
    public void simpleExe() {
        int a = this::add; // DOES NOT COMPILE
    }

    private int add() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

If you want to use method reference that accepts zero arguments and return `int` you can utilize the `IntSupplier` functional interface:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.function.IntSupplier;

@Service
public class MainClass {

    IntSupplier add = () -> {
        // some calculations
        return 42;
    };

    public void simpleExe() {
        int a = add.getAsInt();
        System.out.println("a = " + a);
        // ...
    }
}
```